# Image padding problem with text framed contour labels

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

Consider:

```
f[x_, y_] = 6 - 3 x - 2 y;
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -4, 6}, {y, -2, 2},
 ContourShading -> None,
 Contours -> {-6, 0, 6, 12},
 ContourLabels -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, 
   Text[Framed[z], {x, y}, Background -> LightBlue]],
 Frame -> False,
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 ImagePadding -> All]
```

Which produces this image:

[image]

As you can see, I tried to do some image padding, but not all edges of the text frames on the contour labels are visible.

Any suggestions?

**PlotRangeClipping did not quite work:**

```
f[x_, y_] = 6 - 3 x - 2 y;
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -4, 6}, {y, -2, 2},
 ContourShading -> None,
 Contours -> {-6, 0, 6, 12},
 ContourLabels -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, 
   Text[Framed[z], {x, y}, Background -> LightBlue]],
 Frame -> False,
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

Ok on the top, but not on the bottom.

**PlotRangePadding worked:**

```
f[x_, y_] = 6 - 3 x - 2 y;
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -4, 6}, {y, -2, 2},
 ContourShading -> None,
 Contours -> {-6, 0, 6, 12}, 
 ContourLabels -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, 
   Text[Framed[z], {x, y}, Background -> LightBlue]],
 Frame -> False,
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
```

[image]

Comment: Try  `PlotRangePadding -> 1` instead of `ImagePadding`

Comment: @belisarius  I used PlotRangePadding->Scaled[0.5] from the popup menu and it now looks nice. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The other option to try is `PlotRangeClipping->False`.

Comment: @N.J.Evans. Did not quite work. See update to my original post question. Sorry I didn't include the function originally. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Concerning your disappointment with `PlotRangeClipping -> False` -- you should have used `PlotRange -> All, PlotRangeClipping -> False`

Comment: @m_goldberg. Bingo, that worked. Thanks to both you and N.J.Evans.

Answer (score 3):

The expressions inset by [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html) are not considered in the `PlotRange` used by `ContourPlot`.  We can make the problem more severe and apparent by using wider [`FrameMargins`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameMargins.html):

```
f[x_, y_] := 6 - 3 x - 2 y;

gr = ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -4, 6}, {y, -2, 2}, ContourShading -> None, 
  Contours -> {-6, 0, 6, 12}, 
  ContourLabels -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, 
    Inset[Framed[z, FrameMargins -> 30], {x, y}, Background -> LightBlue]], 
  Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

By resetting `PlotRange -> All` and turning off `PlotRangeClipping` we can include these labels:

```
Show[gr, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

In this case the axis label ends up inside one of the frames because the axes are not extended.  You could add a [`Spacer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Spacer.html) to the y label to improve this.  If you use `PlotRangePadding` instead the axes expand and put the labels further out, but there is no direct way to set the value you need automatically.